# jQuery append on contenteditable adds invisible characters

Tags: jquery, html, sqlite, append

I have an SQLite3 SQL prompt, to which one can append table/column name by clicking it in the list on the right.
Well, that's what I would like it to do. I've been forced to disable this feature because of an error I don't understand.

If I enter the request manually, everything works. But if I use the button to add `table`, I get this error from SQLite :

> in "SELECT * FROM `table`": near "FROM ": syntax error

**This error does not even happen on the appended text !!**

However the input is visually the same. On the console and in the HTML tree (the inspector) too. No special character is shown.
I could check there is an invisible character thanks to a little dropdown that allows me to access previous SQL inputs. The error remains after accessing the faulty input and run it again.

---

Here is the HTML and Javascript so you can see what I want to do and that there's no visible difference :

```js
$('i').click(function() {
    $('#sql-input').append('`' + $(this).data('value') + '`');
});

$('#sql-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($("#sql-input").text());
    /*
        Here is the ajax request to execute the SQL
    */
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<form id="sql-form" action="" method="post">
    <label for="sql-input">SQL PROMPT</label>
    <br />
    <div id="sql-input" style="height: 80px; width: 150px; border: solid 1px black;" contenteditable></div>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
    <button type="button" onclick="console.clear();">clear console</button>
</form>
<div class="list">
    <ul style="cursor: pointer;">
        <li><i data-value="table1">table1</i></li>
        <li><i data-value="col1_1">col1_1</i></li>
        <li><i data-value="col2_1">col2_1</i></li>
        <li><i data-value="col3_1">col3_1</i></li>
        <li><i data-value="table1">table2</i></li>
        <li><i data-value="col1_2">col1_2</i></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Something strange, though, is that If I touch the JQuery-inputted text, the error disappears.

#### What I already tried :

removing the quote marks : `table` => table
using `$().text()` or `$().html()` instead of `$().append()`